# w.r.t. command-line interaction, are Ubuntu and Ubuntu Mate identical

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, ubuntu-mate, canonical

I realize that similar questions have been asked on this site and several times elsewhere. But i want a confirmation to a specific point which is not becoming clear to me on reading these other sources.

I am **not** asking what is the difference between [Ubuntu 16.04](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and [Ubuntu mate 16.04](https://ubuntu-mate.org/blog/ubuntu-mate-xenial-final-release/).

I have Ubuntu 16.04 on a decent desktop. It works well with my current PC but hogs a lot of my resources for its own OS needs which i would very much like to free up for other purposes. So there are are several light-weight linux distros out there to which i can make a switch if freeing up computing resources is my only demand. But i am not a linux expert. I heavily rely on web resources to install applications and code up stuff. For this i find that there are commands scattered all over the web for ubuntu which one can just copy and paste to the terminal and we are done! Due to this massive code bank catering directly to Ubuntu users, i have never shifted to another distro.

But i read about Ubuntu Mate and this is light-weight. All the online documentation directed for the parent Ubuntu distro by Canonical must work perfectly fine in Ubuntu Mate out-of-the-box without any tweaking, at least the command-line interaction. Maybe at GUI level, they are different. Am i right? I believe yes.

But my more important concern is that Ubuntu Mate is not an official Canonical distro, so can one be guaranteed that at least command-line experience for both Ubuntu and Ubuntu mate will be identical in future so that the massive online hep/instructions for the parent Ubuntu distro with unity environment works without glitch for Ubuntu-Mate?

this is just a yes/no question. I have read elsewhere and believe the answer is yes. But i want an explicit confirmation from a reliable source. My main criterion is the ability to make use of the massive online help available for Canonical's Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the base command line tools will be the same. Both use the same package manager, the same set of packages available to the package manager, the same kernel, the same non-gui libraries, and the same shell. If you are interacting with the system below the GUI level, they should be identical.
Any differences in toxins at a higher level can be easily installed.